# Quitar la propiedad del checked de un radiobutton si un input está vacío

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Muy buenas gente.

Tengo una pregunta para que me pudieran colaborar: tengo un `input` tipo texto y dos `radiobutton` en html.

Yo digito un dato dentro de ese `input` y selecciono el radiobutton que `deseo`. Lo que quiero hacer es que si en el `input` no hay ningún dato digitado, se me quite la propiedad checked del `radiobutton` que anteriormente ya había seleccionado.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el código que tienes actualmente para poder ayudarte mejor?

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque sin código, es difícil ayudarte](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2875/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola solo agrega un "false" a la propiedad checked, te dejo un ejemplo simple

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("input").removeAttr("checked");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<input name="name" type="radio" value="VALUE" id="id" checked="false">
<button>RemoveAttr checked del radio button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

copia y pega el código en un bloc de notas y guárdalo como *.html y ve si es lo que ocupas ;)

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda amigo, lo probaré.

Answer (score -1):

```
if( $('.input')==="" ) {
$("#checked").attr("checked","false");
```

}

{

```
  if( $(".input")=== "") {
    $("#checkbox").removeAttr("disabled");
  } else {
    $("#checkbox").attr("disabled", true);
  }
```

Comment: ¿podrías agregar una aclaración?, explicando por qué este código resuelve la duda planteada

Answer (score -2):

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="usr">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr">
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Masculino</label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Femenino</label>
</div>
```

Comment: ya te salio? con jquery lo puedes hacer dinamico lo activa y desactiva si un input esta vacio o tiene datos

Comment: No amigo no me funciona.

Comment: pues ya aparece como respondida tu pregunta  chau