# Quitar la propiedad checked de un radiobutton

Tags: javascript, jquery, radiobutton

¿Por qué siempre se cree empleado? Mi intención es quitarle el atributo checked pero no lo consigo.

Miré [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/117142/quitar-la-propiedad-del-checked-de-un-radiobutton-si-un-input-est%C3%A1-vac%C3%ADo) y creo que lo hago como la solución propone, pero no me funciona.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.radio').click(function() {
    if ($('#radio-Empleado').is(':checked')) {
      $('#radio-Cliente').removeAttr('checked');
      alert('Soy empleado');
    } else if ($('#radio-Cliente').is(':checked')) {
      $('#radio-Empleado').removeAttr('checked');
      alert('Soy cliente');
    } else {
      // Si los ninguno de los dos está selecionado
      alert('Ningún radiobutton seleccionado');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="Contenedores">
  <h2> Define si eres empleado o cliente</h2>

  <div id="Cont-Select-EmpCli">
    <input type="radio" class="radio" id="radio-Empleado">
    <label for="radio-Empleado">Empleado</label>

    <input type="radio" class="radio" id="radio-Cliente">
    <label for="radio-Cliente">Ciente</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

¡Salud!

Answer (score 4):

El código propuesto está mal en varios niveles:

Para empezar, lo que quieres quitar es una propiedad, no un atributo. Deberías usar `.removeProp('checked')` o `.prop('checked', false)`.
Puedes ver la diferencia entre ambos en [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre attr y prop en jQuery?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/100441/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-attr-y-prop-en-jquery)

En segundo lugar, no compruebas qué radio se ha pulsado, simplemente miras si empleado está "checked" y, si no lo está, miras a cliente. Por tanto, si empleado está ya marcado, da igual si he pulsado en cliente o no, nunca se cambian los valores.

En tercer lugar, no necesitas nada de código, basta con que ambos radio buttons tengan el mismo nombre para que sólo pueda estar pulsado uno de ellos:

```html
<label>Cliente</label>
<input type="radio" name="test" value="cliente">
<label>Empleado</label>
<input type="radio" name="test" value="empleado">
```